# Clean install from Ubuntu 10.04 to LUbuntu 10.10 without losing data?

Tags: 10.10, installation, upgrade

I have the same situation with this one.
[Upgrade from Kubuntu 9.10 to Ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4119/upgrade-from-kubuntu-9-10-to-ubuntu-10-04).

But I am planning to install LUbuntu 10.10 via USB on my netbook after the release. I have only one partition (and don't have any plans yet to create another partition). Is it possible to keep the /home folder while installing aside from backing it up to an external drive and do a clean install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's entirely possible to do just that. Simply run the installer, and when you get to the partitioning options, go for manual partitioning, and mark your single partition as root (/) **BUT DO NOT FORMAT IT**.

Proceed from here as normal and the installer will simply overwrite the existing system files, and anything else that isn't a system file (such as the contents of your home directory) will be ignored. I've done it myself, though I was reinstalling my Ubuntu 10.04 installation, rather than moving to a separate distro, but I can't see there being any problem with that.

Good luck.

Comment: Any risk of problems with ecryptfs-encrypted $HOME during this procedure? Or not, because all the files ecryptfs need are in my $HOME?

Comment: If you keep all your credentials the same i.e. username, password and hostname, since those are the three variables used to encrypt/decrypt your home directory, then it should be fine.