# Black borders in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04

[similiar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal) but for ubuntu 16.

I was trying to open google earth on chrome but was getting a message along the lines that I did not have any hardware accelaration.

So I followed some askubuntu questions and was able to get it working by enabling something in chrome's flags. But know I have the black bars and borders everywhere in ubuntu. Even the terminal is black and I can't see anything.

Please help

Comment: Did you try the answers provided in the linked question?

Comment: Yes..other than the mir one.... as opening the link says it is specific for ubuntu 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling my nvidia graphics driver as mentioned by the accepted answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) link.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have experienced situation aforementioned and this helped them.

Try:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Why?

Because, this occurs when `ubuntu-desktop` is broken...

Comment: done did not work

Comment: Are you using ubuntu desktop or other (like xfce)?

Comment: in systemsetting > details, it shows ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is obvious fault of `ubuntu-desktop`, maybe do you mind to try `xubuntu`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/65861/how-to-i-change-from-ubuntu-to-xubuntu

Comment: WIll it work? I think the problem is with my graphic drivers or something? I will wait for a few hours for some other solution. If I don't get one then I will   go to xubuntu. If it isn't a problem, please upvote the question for visibility