# How to remove Ubuntu-desktop while keeping Xubuntu-desktop?

Tags: xubuntu, gui, desktop-environments

Today I had problems with a blank screen after the log-in page of my **Xubuntu**. This problem was resolved by re-installing **xubuntu-desktop** through this process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

BUT. Before I did this, I mistakenly installed the **ubuntu-desktop** via the same process of:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

**How do I cleanly and safely remove UBUNTU-DESKTOP while retaining my XUBUNTU GUI?**

I'm still quite new Linux, and would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I change from Ubuntu to Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65861/how-to-i-change-from-ubuntu-to-xubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

to make sure that you are not on ubuntu-desktop

then

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I make sure this process doesn't delete any (meta) packages I'm currently using on my Xubuntu?

Comment: you can always reinstall xubuntu-desktop `sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop`